# Most Complete Course Materials Taught Using Munkres? G.F. Simmons? Erwine Kreyszig?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, online-resources

I'm looking for online resources offering the materials (i.e. lecture notes, homeworks / assignments with solutions, exams with solutions, and videos of lectures) of a first course in topology taught using Munkres' *Topology*, 2nd edition, or G.F. Simmon's *Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis*.

I've found the materials of a 2004 course at MIT OcW.

Where else do I look? Where is the most complete and comprehensive set of materials available for such a course?

And, any such online resources please for course materials of a first course in functional analysis course taught using Erwine Kreyszig's *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications*?

Answer (score 3):

I found this series of lectures on Topology by [Bruno Zimmerman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXIcas22MtQ&list=PLLq_gUfXAnkl8bjQh-hGQ9u24xZP9x0dx) which uses the book by Munkres, and another series of lectures by [Greg Morrow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebesx6pF8mg) which uses the book by Kreyszig. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much. Can you please also dig out another similar functional analysis course on Kreyszig? And, can you please also find me some sets of lecture notes, assignments with solutions, and exams with solutions on these functional analysis and topology courses taught using any of these books?